# Trying to get assertTrue junit to pass but it always fails

Tags: junit

So basically I want this test to pass should a valid name , like Paul, be entered. However, the junit always fails and I just cant figure out why. Any help is greatly appreciated. The code actually works when I run it also.

```
public int searchCustomer(String fName) throws SQLException
{
    displayAllCustomers();
    if(fName.isEmpty())
    {   
    System.out.println("Please enter a name to search: ");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    fName = scanner.nextLine();
    }

    String fnameQ="Select * from customers where first_name='"+fName+"';";

    try
    { 
        rs = stmt.executeQuery(fnameQ);
        while (rs.next()) 
        { 
            int cus_id = rs.getInt("cus_id"); 
            int reg_id=rs.getInt("reg_id");
            String first_name = rs.getString("first_name"); 
            String last_name = rs.getString("last_name");
            int dob=rs.getInt("dob");
            String address_line1=rs.getString("address_line1");
            String address_line2=rs.getString("address_line2");
            String eircode=rs.getString("eircode");
            System.out.println("" + cus_id + " ¦ " + reg_id + " ¦ " + first_name + " ¦ " + last_name + " ¦ " + dob+ " ¦ " + address_line1 + " ¦ " + address_line2 + " ¦ " + eircode);

        } 

    } 
    catch (SQLException sqle) 
    { 
        System.out.println("Error: failed to display all products."); 
        System.out.println(sqle.getMessage());
        System.out.println(fnameQ);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Here is the junit test.

```
public  void testsearchCustomer0001() throws SQLException {

    newsagentDatabase testObject = new newsagentDatabase();

    try{
    assertEquals(1,testObject.searchCustomer("Paul"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        fail("This should be true");
        }
    }
```

I am using junit3 if that is needed info. The actual aim of the code is to output info from a database. If you have any questions ask them!!! I will be actively checking here.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your database. What does the code print out? If `searchCustomer` doesn't return 1, what *does* it return?

Comment: searchCustomer prints out a row from the database. Im using return 1 so I know if the code works and passes the junit, if that makes any sense.

Comment: What is the code output?

Comment: Once you enter a name , in this case Paul, this is what is printed.

1 ¦ 1 ¦ Paul ¦ Armstrong ¦ 1976 ¦ 13 Old Lane ¦ Athlone ¦ N65 EW21

Comment: Is that what gets printed when you run the JUnit test? Add a `e.printStackTrace()` to the catch block and see what happens.

Comment: It says e cannot be resolved

Comment: Inside the catch block, right before `fail` and right after the open bracket.